# vba code refactoring - are there any tools to assist?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to refactor my VBA code. I am so used to using refactoring in Java-based IDEs for a number of years. Does VBA editor support any refactoring or are there any add-ins? MZ Tools did not have any such functionality.

I want to be able to do at least the following:
1. Rename variables
2. Split Procedures into sub-procedures to make the code more readable
3. Change the scope of the variable from global to procedure and vice-versa

Comment: Haven't used it till date. But see of this link helps? http://visualbasic.about.com/od/usingvbnet/a/refact_4.htm

Comment: Have you tried the Visual Basic version of Resharper? I know VBA is different, but it may work for most of your needs.

Comment: I don't rate your chances - it was a long time before C# & VB.NET even got these features. I guess the thinking is that if you're needing to do any kind of heavyweight code, you'll want to start using more heavyweight languages...

Comment: Robbie Dee, refactoring is useful in any program under any circumstances. After 10 lines of code you can find yourself refactoring already, so it should be a basic tool in any and all IDEs. Unfortunately the world is adapting slowly.

Comment: I think you'll need to do it the old fashioned way, since VBA is an old fashioned IDE.

Answer (score 37):

> **Disclaimer**: I'm heavily involved with this project.

---

[**Rubberduck**](http://www.rubberduckvba.com) is an open-source add-in for the VBA/VB6 IDE under [very] active development, that includes this functionality.

Version 1.3 includes a *Rename* refactoring:

[image: rename refactoring]

Version 2.0 (beta available, still stabilizing) includes a dozen refactorings:

[image: Rubberduck 2.0 refactorings]

- *Introduce Parameter* promotes a local variable to a parameter
- *Introduce Field* promotes a local variable to module scope
- *Encapsulate Field* turns a public field into a property
- *Move Closer to Usage* moves a field that's only used in 1 procedure, into that procedure. Or moves a local variable immediately above its first use.
- *Extract Interface* lets you pick what class members to extract into an interface, creates a new class modules with stubs for them, and makes the original class implement the extracted interface.
- *Implement Interface* creates stubs for all members of an unimplemented interface, so you don't need to create them manually by selecting them one by one in the code pane dropdown:

  ```
  Implements IClass1

  Public Sub IClass1_DoSomething()
      Err.Raise 5 'TODO implement interface member
  End Sub

  Public Function IClass1_GetFoo() As Integer
      Err.Raise 5 'TODO implement interface member
  End Function

  Sub DoSomething()

  End Sub

  Function GetFoo() As Integer

  End Function
  ```

---

More refactoring tools are on the project's roadmap (including *Extract Method*), which you can follow on [GitHub](http://www.github.com/rubberduck-vba/rubberduck).

Comment: Can you add those explanations to the "Refactoring" or "Tutorials" section of your wiki on GitHub? I wondered what those tools did, but didn't know where to look.

Comment: @ShawnV.Wilson gosh the wiki is so out of date, it's not even funny. And then there's the website and blog that should have this information too.. So much to do, so little time - the repository's wiki can be edited/improved by literally anyone though.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Is the wiki the only source of documentation, currently?

Answer (score 4):

The only 'refactoring' tool I know of in VBA is Ctrl+F and Ctrl+R.

Comment: Don't forget Ctrl-H to replace.

Comment: This sounds more like sarcasm than a useful answer.

Comment: or Save As `.xlsx` xD. But seriously, Ctrl+H Replace also has `Use Pattern Matching` option but it doesn't work with more than one line.

Answer (score 2):

I use V-Tools for refactoring-like work as it will do find / replace in objects, not just VBA code.
http://www.skrol29.com/us/vtools.php

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is.... almost

In the good old days i used this one.
http://www.moshannon.com/speedferret.html

helped me alot and I think i have the 3.5" disks somewere ;)

The trick is to copy your excel code to Access or VB6 and do your refactoring there.
Replacing scope: solution is creative naming and using replace. 
spitting procedures... well thats a manual I'm sorry.

It's usually not worth it unless you have some serious excel vba code, I would recoment converting most of it into c# or VB.Net dll where you can do refactoring, testing and some modern magic and only do as little you can in VBA.

Comment: Yeah, IIRC, speed ferret is still available, but I don't think it has seen any meaningful development in 10 years. I believe Rubberduck VBA adds more features and works on more VBA hosts, and it's free and under active development.