# Excel VBA multiple error handling in the same procedure

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

I have previously used error handling in VBA successfully, but when trying to use several error handling blocks I can't figure out how to do it.

The code I've written looks like this:

```
...

  On Error GoTo ErrorHandler1
  shpArrow1.Left = shpLine.Left + shpLine.Width * Min(Sqr(Calculations.Range("cVolProduct").value / Calculations.Range("cVolRefIndices").value), 2) / 2 - shpArrow1.Width / 2
  shpTag1.Left = shpLine.Left + shpLine.Width * Min(Sqr(Calculations.Range("cVolProduct").value / Calculations.Range("cVolRefIndices").value), 2) / 2 - shpTag1.Width / 2
  shpArrow2.Left = shpLine.Left + shpLine.Width * Min(Sqr(Calculations.Range("cVolUnderlyings").value / Calculations.Range("cVolRefIndices").value), 2) / 2 - shpArrow2.Width / 2
  shpTag2.Left = shpLine.Left + shpLine.Width * Min(Sqr(Calculations.Range("cVolUnderlyings").value / Calculations.Range("cVolRefIndices").value), 2) / 2 - shpTag2.Width / 2
  shpIndexLine.Left = shpLine.Left + shpLine.Width / 2 - shpIndexLine.Width / 2
  GoTo NoError1
ErrorHandler1:
  shpArrow1.Left = shpLine.Left - shpArrow1.Width / 2
  shpTag1.Left = shpLine.Left - shpTag1.Width / 2
  shpArrow2.Left = shpLine.Left - shpArrow2.Width / 2
  shpTag2.Left = shpLine.Left - shpTag2.Width / 2
  shpIndexLine.Left = shpLine.Left + shpLine.Width / 2 - shpIndexLine.Width / 2
  errorRelativeRisk = 1
NoError1:
  On Error GoTo 0

  On Error GoTo ErrorHandler2
  Output.ChartObjects("ChartHistoryUnderlyings").Activate
  ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).CrossesAt = ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale
  ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).CrossesAt = ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale
  GoTo NoError2
ErrorHandler2:
  errorHistUnderl = 1
NoError2:
  On Error GoTo 0

...
```

The second error handling block does not work. I'm guessing that I don't quit the first error handling block correctly. Have tried to find an answer that works for me but without success.

Greatful for any help!

Comment: Do the `...` stand for `Private Sub DoSomething()` and `End Sub` respectively, or there's more to it? I think your code could be easier to follow if you [extracted a method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29991570/1188513) out of each "block", each with its own error handling; basically you need to untangle this `GoTo Mess`.

Comment: Yes the `...` stands for start and end of sub, but there's some more simple calculations which should not affect the error handling. Basically both of the error handling blocks works if I only use one of them, but to use both maybe I have to "hide" the code by making two short subs instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Having two or more error-handling subroutines in a procedure is definitely a design smell; that's not how VBA error-handling works.

Basically you have this:

```
Sub Foo()
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler1
    '(code)

ErrHandler1:
    '(error handling code)

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler2
    '(code)

ErrHandler2:
    '(error handling code)

End Sub
```

When an error occurs in the first block, VBA jumps to `ErrHandler1` *and still thinks it's in an error-handling subroutine when it gets to the 2nd block*.

You need to `Resume` somewhere, to tell VBA "I've handled everything I had to handle".

So instead of "falling-through" into the `NoError1` subroutine, your `ErrorHandler1` subroutine should end with a `Resume` jump:

```
Resume NoError1
```

And the `ErrorHandler2` should also end with a `Resume` jump:

```
Resume NoError2
```

That way VBA knows it's out of "error handling mode" and back into "normal execution".

But I'd strongly recommend considering separate methods/procedures instead of labelled subroutines.

Answer (score 1):

The solution would be to apply `On Error GoTo -1`.
It resets the error handling in VBA so that enables you to use multiple `On Error GoTo` statements.

```
>   Sub Asd()
    Range(Cells(7, 1), Cells(LastRow, 2)).Select
    On Error GoTo hello
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
hello: 
Cells(1, 1).Value = "Error 1"
On Error GoTo -1
 Range(Cells(7, 4), Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).Select
On Error GoTo Hell
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "0"
Hell: 
Cells(1, 1).Value = "Error 2"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you should put in `End Sub` after each error handling code

Comment: Surely you mean `Exit Sub` ?