# How to use multiple error handlers in VBA

Tags: vba

I have tried to use multiple error handling in a VBA code

```
Sub ErrorTestMultiple()

Test1:
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler1
        y = 6 / 0
        GoTo Test2

ErrHandler1:
        Cells(4, "H") = "Test 1 failed"
        Cells(4, "I") = Err.Description


Test2:

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler2
        y = 6 / 0 ' Process stop here - Why is the 2nd Error handler not working?
        GoTo Test3

ErrHandler2:
        Cells(5, "H") = "Test 2 failed"
        Cells(5, "I") = Err.Description

Test3:

End Sub
```

I tried adding resume following example in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33877029/excel-vba-multiple-error-handling-in-the-same-procedure) but it didn't work iter

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reset the error handler with `On Errro Goto -1` beforehand, i.e.

```
Sub ErrorTestMultiple()

Test1:
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler1
        y = 6 / 0
        GoTo Test2

ErrHandler1:
        Cells(4, "H") = "Test 1 failed"
        Cells(4, "I") = Err.Description


Test2:

    On Error GoTo -1
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler2

        y = 6 / 0 ' Process stop here - Why is the 2nd Error handler not working?
        GoTo Test3

ErrHandler2:
        Cells(5, "H") = "Test 2 failed"
        Cells(5, "I") = Err.Description

Test3:

End Sub
```

**But** this is **not good practise**. Furhter reading [here](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling/#On_Error_GoTo_-1)

**PS** You could re-structure the above code like that

```
Sub ErrorTestMultiple()

    Dim y As Double

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    y = 6 / 0
    y = 6 / 0

    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:

    Dim j As Long
    j = j + 1

    Cells(3 + j, "H") = "Test " & j & " failed"
    Cells(3 + j, "I") = Err.Description

    Resume Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub ErrorTestMultiple()

Test1:
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler1
        y = 6 / 0
    on error goto 0
        GoTo Test2

ErrHandler1:
        Cells(4, "H") = "Test 1 failed"
        Cells(4, "I") = Err.Description

         Resume next

Test2:

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler2
        y = 6 / 0
    on error goto 0
        GoTo Test3

ErrHandler2:
        Cells(5, "H") = "Test 2 failed"
        Cells(5, "I") = Err.Description

         Resume next
Test3:

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested of Storax.

One Error Handler is applied per Sub Routine. Thus, the Error handling will only apply based on the first instance of the Error call.

So in order to handle multiple Error Calls. To start, try to break your subroutine into smaller routine.

Or hence, the main rule of Error Handling if you know what will happen or the expected behaviour of your program no need to handle it during "Run-time".

A proper code structuring most of the time may do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can have mutiple error handlers in a procedure.  The trick is to avoid the common example of Goto Label.  Instead you should use a combination of On Error Resume Next and On Error Goto O to emulate a try catch block.

```
Sub ErrorTestMultiple()

    ' Test 1
    On Error Resume Next
    Y = 6 / 0
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        On Error GoTo 0
        Cells(4, "H") = "Test 1 failed"
        Cells(4, "I") = Err.Description
        Exit Sub

    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    ' Test 2
    On Error Resume Next
    Y = 6 / 0 
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        On Error GoTo 0
        Cells(5, "H") = "Test 2 failed"
        Cells(5, "I") = Err.Description
        Exit Sub
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Some good reading here on alternative strategies to Goto ErrorHandler

https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2019/05/