What exactly is the scope of the On Error Resume Next statement?
I tested Microsoft's statement about the scope regarding the On Error Resume Next statement:

An On Error Resume Next statement becomes inactive when another procedure is called, so you should execute an On Error Resume Next statement in each called routine if you want inline error handling within that routine.

But in my test On Error Resume Next did not become inactive at all after calling a function or procedure which I deliberately left ending with de line On Error Goto 0.
Sub CalledSub ()
    MsgBox "Hello"
    On error goto 0
End Sub
    
Sub CallingSub ()
    On Error Resume Next
    Call CalledSub
    MsgBox 1/0
End Sub

I thought this would raise an error. But this is not the case.
What is going on?

Sorry about the poor quality of the code. Something went wrong there.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60900344/6600940

@Storax Does not seem related.

What they meant in the documentation is that the On Error setting that you have in your procedure does not propagate to the procedure you are calling. They did not mean that the act of calling another procedure resets the On Error Resume Next you have in your current procedure. If it did, On Error Resume Next would be completely useless.

Ok, then I will put it more directly:  https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling/#The_On_Error_Statement

And, of course, another source for more insight: https://rubberduckvba.blog/2019/05/

Does this answer your question? What are some good patterns for VBA error handling?

There are 3 rules about error handling flow, and if you think about it, they are rather logic:

Every routine is responsible of their own error handling. A called subroutine can not influence the error handling of a calling subroutine. This is the reason you don't see an error - the On Error Resume Next of your calling routine stays active. As a programmer, you don't want that a called routine influences the flow of your code.

If a runtime error happens and a routine handles it (via On Error Resume Next or On Error Goto 0), it is seen as handled and nothing will happen with it any more - program will simply continue.

If a runtime error happens and a routine doesn't handle it, it is "bubbling" to the top: It is raised to the calling routine. If this handles it, okay - if not, it is raised to the calling routine of the calling routine (and so on). If none of it handles it (and there is no "higher" calling routine), it is handled by the VBA runtime by displaying the known error dialog.


Examples:
(1) Your code - the called routine doesn't influence the error handling of the calling routine. The calling routine creates an error and handles it (by ignoring it).
Sub CalledSub1()
    MsgBox "Hello"
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub

Sub CallingSub1()
    On Error Resume Next
    Call CalledSub1
    MsgBox 1 / 0
End Sub

(2) The called sub has a runtime error but handles it itself - no error is displayed and the execution continue (you *will" see the MsgBox "I continue")
Sub CalledSub2()
    On Error Resume Next
    MsgBox 1 / 0
End Sub

Sub CallingSub2()
    Call CalledSub2
    MsgBox "I continue"
End Sub

(3) The called routine creates an error but doesn't handle it. The execution of the called sub is stopped (you will not see the MsgBox "Hello") and the error is bubbling to the calling routine where it is handled and the execution continue (you *will" see the MsgBox "I continue")
Sub CalledSub3()
    MsgBox 1 / 0
    MsgBox "Hello"
End Sub

Sub CallingSub3()
    On Error Resume Next
    Call CalledSub3
    MsgBox "I continue"
End Sub

(4) The called routine creates an error but doesn't handle it. Again, the error is bubbling to the called routine. As now the calling routine doesn't handle it either, it is displayed as VBA runtime error. Execution is stopped (you will not see the MsgBox "I continue" as the program is stopped before that.)
Sub CalledSub4()
    MsgBox 1 / 0
    MsgBox "Hello"
End Sub

Sub CallingSub4()
    Call CalledSub4
    MsgBox "I continue"
End Sub


I always assumed that the On Error Goto 0 line at the end of the called routine would negate the On error Resume Next in the calling routine from the point where the code resumes in the latter routine. Thanks for answering my question everyone.

That's a fine answer. I'm nit-picking here, but In case 4, the Hello message box won't show either. Maybe add this to the explanation since it may not be obvious to everyone.

In completion to the first very detailed answer, I will like to also show the way able to catch the error, show its number and description in another MsgBox and then call the other Sub:
Sub CalledSub()
    MsgBox "Hello!"
End Sub
    
Sub CallingSub()
    On Error Resume Next
     MsgBox 1 / 0
     If Err.number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Err number: " & Err.number & vbCrLf & _
               "Err description: " & Err.Description
     End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    CalledSub
End Sub

So, it is able to overpass the error and also to show its number/description...
Or if you are expecting the division by zero error, you can try the next way:
Sub CallingSub_bis()
    On Error Resume Next
     MsgBox 1 / 0
     If Err.number = 11 Then
        MsgBox "Division by zero error...", vbCritical, "Fatal error without error handling"
     End If
     On Error GoTo 0
     CalledSub
End Sub


In addition to the two previous answers, I would like to draw attention to one more aspect.
If you use On Error Resume Next in the procedure, errors are not handled, and when an error occurs, the Err value remains unchanged even after exiting the procedure. If you want to avoid this, you should use On Error GoTo 0 before exiting the procedure. It is also important when you call procedure in a loop.
In contrast, when we apply On Error GoTo ErrHandler after error handling is complete, the value of Err is cancelled.
Sub CalledSub1()
    On Error Resume Next
    MsgBox 1 / 0
    MsgBox "Hello!"
'   On Error GoTo 0
End Sub

Sub CalledSub2()
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    MsgBox 1 / 0
    MsgBox "Hello!"
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err
End Sub

Sub CallingSub()
 '  CalledSub1
    CalledSub2
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Err number: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & _
               "Err description: " & Err.Description
    End If
'    On Error GoTo 0
    MsgBox Err
End Sub


I think the best way to detect errors and trace them back to the sub that caused them is to run this code line: If Err <> 0 then call Err_Handler("Procedure name") just before calling each function or routine. Of course you also place the same error trap at the very bottom of the main sub. I think then all errors are shown and at the same time the code will resume.
