# How to use error handling multiple time in for loop?

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling, automation

```
For Each cell In Workbooks("workbook.xlsm").Sheets("sheet1").Range("P5:P12").Cells
sheetname = cell.Value
Windows("new workbook.xlsx").Activate
Worksheets(division).Select
On Error GoTo SKIPCODE

{code}

SKIPCODE:
Next
```

While running this code if the sheet with name in range of P5-P12 does not exist it gives an error. FOr first such occurrence error is handled and loop continues but for second occurrence code breaks.
Can someone help on this??

Comment: Check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33877029/excel-vba-multiple-error-handling-in-the-same-procedure and also this is a nice enough guide https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling/

Comment: Very funny. You are not revealing the crucial part (`{code}`) for an accurate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reset the error handler object after having "handled" the error, in your case by just skipping the iteration. Usually this is done automatically by the `resume` keyword, however, since you are not using resume because you are essentially just ignoring the error, you have to do it manually by using `On Error GoTo -1`

Try adding that to your code like this:

```vb
For Each cell In Workbooks("workbook.xlsm").Sheets("sheet1").Range("P5:P12").Cells
    sheetname = cell.Value
    Windows("new workbook.xlsx").Activate
    Worksheets(division).Select
    On Error GoTo SKIPCODE

    '{code}

SKIPCODE:
    On Error GoTo -1
Next
```