# For loop incomplete

Tags: excel, if-statement, for-loop, vba

Im getting an error that my next is without a for :/
What am I missing here. I want it to check column C (cells(y,3)) and if its blank, then look at column A, find the matching value in G and then give the corresponding value in F in column C. And if it's not blank, then move onto the next cell vertically.

```
    Dim x As Double
    Dim y As Double
    For y = 2 To 84212
        For x = 531 To 632

            If IsEmpty(Cells(y, 3)) Then
                If Cells(y, 1).Value = Cells(x, 6).Value Then Cells(y, 3).Value = Cells(x,7).Value
            Else: Next x
            Else: Next y
End Sub
```

Comment: I suggest you use (free) Smart Indenter: http://www.oaltd.co.uk/indenter/default.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loops and If statements should look something like:

```
Dim x As Long ' Use Long, rather than Double for integer arithmetic
Dim y As Long
For y = 2 To 84212
    If IsEmpty(Cells(y, 3)) Then ' Perform this test before starting the 
                                 ' inner loop, thus saving 102 iterations
        For x = 531 To 632
            If Cells(y, 1).Value = Cells(x, 6).Value Then
                Cells(y, 3).Value = Cells(x, 7).Value
                Exit For ' No use looking at other "x" rows once a match has been found
            End If
        Next x
    End If
Next y
```

Also notice how indenting code allows you to correctly ensure `If` statements are matched with `End If`, and `For` statements are matched with `Next` statements.  Apart from ensuring your code is valid, it also will make it easier to read.  (Notice that I tried editing your question to indent code [something we often do to make it easier for other people who are trying to answer your question] and none of the statements line up - I ended up giving up because of the two `Else` statements with only one Block `If` to match them to.)

Comment: Also is there anyway that VBA itself would indent for me while im writing the code or does that have to be done manually?

Comment: regarding the for loop on x, why is there not an else, as in if it does not match, should it not be given a statement to then move onto the next x?

Comment: @IsraShaikh - if there is no `Else` leg of the `If` statement, nothing is performed if the logical expression evaluates to `False` - execution just moves down to whatever comes after the `End If`.

Comment: @IsraShaikh Re indentation, the VBA IDE won't automatically indent for you, but there are add-ins available.  I don't use any but I think I could recommend RubberDuck (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/29991570/6535336) simply because two (at least) of the better SO answerers of VBA questions (comintern and Mat's Mug) are involved in its development.  There is also a link added by iDevlop as a comment to your question that recommends another add-in.

Answer (score 0):

You have started two FOR loops and did not end any of them. You just put them in Else statement instead of ending IF:

```
Dim x As Double
Dim y As Double
For y = 2 To 84212
For x = 531 To 632

If IsEmpty(Cells(y, 3)) Then
If Cells(y, 1).Value = Cells(x, 6).Value Then Cells(y, 3).Value = Cells(x,7).Value Then
'Do something
End if
End if

Next x ' End loop with x variable
Next y ' End loop with y variable
       ' Both x and y can be omitted. This is just for clarifications.
End Sub
```

Comment: Your `If <expression> Then <statement> Then` statement will not work.